# Create yeoman generator from json instead of prompts?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

When I create a project, I first create a project.json file (used internally, not as part of some package). Then for some projects I run yeoman with our own custom generators.
What I would like is for yeoman to pick up my projects.json and read that instead of prompting me for settings.
Is this possible, and if so; how do I do this? Basically I think I need to know:

1. How do I load the file from the project-root into index.js (and defer to prompts if it doesn't exist)
2. How to I bind the properties from the json to 'this'.

Answer (score 1):

A Yeoman generator is just a searchable and composable Node.js project running within the context of Yeoman.

As so, it can do **anything**.

So, if you want to write a generator reading a `project.json` configuration file to know what to generate - well just do it!

http://yeoman.io/authoring/